# Whats the best format to turn a render into a poster?

Tags: rendering

I am interested in turning some of my blender works into posters for my house. Does blender save in a high enough resolution or format ( sorry I'm not very sure on these terms ) that can produce a high enough quality poster? Thanks in advance!

Comment: if I read every thing correctly, its showing 300dpi is good for posters and the calculator puts that to 6000 x 9000 pixels. so I change the render resolution to 6000 x 9000, and 1080 samples., and save as bmp. sound like the right neighborhood?

Comment: Don't use bmp, use tiff (or png)

Comment: The [_Render to Print_](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/Render%20to%20Print) add-on calculates all that for you. it includes many presets of standard print dimensions.

Comment: thank you all who have answered. blender would be impossible to learn without people like you!

Comment: You might also need to convert to CMYK to be sure the conversion isn't skipped by the printer or badly done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First determine what size (in cm or inches) you want the poster to be.

Then decide on the quality of the print: find out how many DPIs you need for the purposes you are after. 300 DPI is the common reslolution for prints, but it might vary.

Find an online calculator to to determine the dimensions in **pixels** for your image you need to render.

Set your scene in blender to render using those dimensions.

Save to a Tiff or PNG file.

The biggest challenge for such a project is that you can preserve the colors and quality you see on your monitor to those possible on printed media. For that it's better to consult with the printing service you'll use,and find out from them what kind of image format they prefer to work with, and how to deal with color conversion from RBG to CMYK.

If possible print a small test.