# Need to render a VERY HQ 2.4 meter tall image

Tags: hdri

Need to render a VERY HQ 2.4 meter tall image for print. How can I achieve this without my computer exploding? :)

Thanks
Logan

Comment: More detail would allow us to be more helpful as well as how this question relates to Blender?

Comment: The [Render to Print addon](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/Render%20to%20Print) will let you set the physical dimensions and DPI and calculate the resolution you'll need to render at.

Comment: related, possible duplicate question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58505/whats-the-best-format-to-turn-a-render-into-a-poster/58509#58509

Comment: duplicate: [How to render a 30K image with cycles?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/16251/2217)

Answer (score 1):

1. For print a 2.4 meter billboard you are absolutely don't need it to be in "HQ". Check this answers [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/26354/i-need-to-print-an-image-a-certain-size-what-dimensions-and-resolutions-should).
2. You don't have to render all in once - you can render layers and then compose them. Explained [here](https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/how-to-render-a-complex-scene-without-crashing/)
3. I can presume that if you rendering a work for this kind of printing, you will have to make some post-production work - color correction, text layout etc. So the right workflow is to render the elements you need in blender and than combine them in your preferred editor, trying to make minimum layout work in blender.